# jQuery Mobile data-collapsed="false"

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I'm confused by the example on the jQuery Mobile site, [collapsible set with 5 sections](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html).
It looks like section 1 should be open, but it's not.

And section 3 says "I'm hidden by default", but it's the one that is open in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

That example don't have anything to do with real example shown below. Example you are referring to has 2 elements, and real bottom example has five.

This is a bottom example, you can see it in a page source:

```
    <div data-role="collapsible-set">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
            <h3>Section 1</h3>
            <p>I'm the collapsible content in a set so this feels like an accordion. I'm open by default because I have the <code>data-collapsed="false"</code> attribute.</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>Section 2</h3>
            <p>I'm the collapsible content in a set so this feels like an accordion. I'm hidden by default because I have the "collapsed" state; you need to expand the header to see me.</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
            <h3>Section 3</h3>
            <p>I'm the collapsible content in a set so this feels like an accordion. I'm hidden by default because I have the "collapsed" state; you need to expand the header to see me.</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>Section 4</h3>
            <p>I'm the collapsible content in a set so this feels like an accordion. I'm hidden by default because I have the "collapsed" state; you need to expand the header to see me.</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>Section 5</h3>
            <p>I'm the collapsible content in a set so this feels like an accordion. I'm hidden by default because I have the "collapsed" state; you need to expand the header to see me.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Right.  So look at section 3.

Comment: This is just a typo on their side. jQuery Mobile documentation is full of error's, missing or wrong info, not to mention outdated data.